# Any functionality in a MongoDB Aggregation like a simple "regex replace"?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to create a step in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline which will replace the value of a full Social Security Number (like `"123-45-6789"`) with a masked value, preserving the last four digits (like `"XXX-XX-6789"`).

I see `$replaceAll` and `$replaceOne` but it looks like those only accept string literals, not regex expressions. I see there is a regex find that looks like it can very clumsily fit into a replace stage:

```js
"maskedSsn" : {
    "$replaceOne" : { 
        "input" : "$ssn",
        "find" : { 
            "$regexFind" : { 
                "input" : "$ssn", 
                "regex" : "\\d{3}-\\d{2}\\-"
            }
        },
        "replacement" : "XXX-XX-"
    }
}
```

But with this I get the error `"$replaceOne requires that 'find' be a string, found: {match: \"000-00-\", idx: 0, captures: []}` (the SSN is mocked, random data here). I'm not sure how to just get the `"match"` out of the resultant object as part of this step. I *could* add this regex match as a different field, then get the match in this stage of my aggregation for a simple string replacement, but I would prefer to keep all the logic in one step if possible.

It's hard for me to believe that this isn't possible in one step, with something like a regex replace (which is a feature of every language I've used). Is there a functionality that I'm missing?

Comment: [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G-L8WFk2aQ9) might seem tedious, but it works for your case by splitting with `-` and masking on all tokens except the last one. After the masking, the result is rejoined to form the masked SSN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no generalized regexReplace operator in MongoDB.

You could kind of get where you want using $regexFind, like

```
{$regexFind: {
   input:"$ssn",
   regex:"^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-(\\d{4})$"
}}
```

That would return an object similar to:

```
{ 
  match: "123-45-6789",
  idx: 0
  captures: ["6789"]
}
```

You could use $getField, $arrayElemAt and $concat to extract the captures part, then do what you need with that.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$addFields: {
      maskedssn: {
        $concat: [
          "XXX-XX-",
          {$arrayElemAt: [
              {$getField: {
                  field: "captures",
                  input: {$regexFind: {
                      input: "$ssn",
                      regex: "^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-(\\d{4})$"
                    }}
              }},
              0
          ]}
        ]
      }
 }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ow_GQVSzSq2)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I was really hoping I was just missing something but your answer is a great way to do this. Rather than create the field through multiple aggregation steps, I realized (because of your great answer) that I can just concat a string with a substring which is much simpler for my case. Thanks so much!